# Drupal Rules: Send email then Contact Custom Field Value was updated

Tags: drupal, drupal-rules

There are two different "Reactions on Event" if you create a Drupal Rule: 
"CiviCRM Contact has been updated" and "Custom field has been updated" (which is clearly about someone edits Field, not value attached to Contact).

What kind of conditions should be set to get value of a Contact's custom field altered?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve functional?

Comment: Sure: grab one of the values of custom Contact field via Drupal Rules after it was changed and use it in Drupal Rules actions. Say, we have a set of Custom Fields for Contact and drop-down/select with a few options. Each time a new option is being selected, option value is to be grabbed and send via Drupal Rules Email. Hope it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, it does not really make sense functional. As far as I understand, when a user select a value from a drop down someone else gets an e-mail? Why would you do that?

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP Sorry for sound rude, yet any chance we could stay on a subject and get back from "why" question to "how" question, if only you have something to say about the latter, please? Really appreciate your help, just not in a mood for useless chatting ;-)

Comment: Does the implementation have to be Drupal Rules? Maybe you could achieve what you want to achieve (which I don't know what it is) with CiviRules. CiviRules does have a trigger contact changed and then you could send an e-mail. CiviRules also has some kind of conditions to check which field has been changed

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP Thank you for the suggestion, I've tried CiviRules also but probably not hard enough, at least at the moment haven't been able to find required combination of puzzle pieces. Going to give it a go one more time, thank you for reminder about CiviRules!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out Jaap Jansma - CiviCooP  was right, CiviRules ( and Email Api for sending emails - a missing piece from my previous attempts ) can do the job nicely. CiviRules can handle any Contact change nicely. Kudos to  Jaap Jansma - CiviCooP!